# `How to change between list view and grid view and also keep the current state after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php

I need to toggle between list view and grid view which i was able to do using js to change the css but the problem is if a user refresh the page the default view is restored, how can I make this, probably append the view name to the url so that the current view will remain after user refresh page. example having the following URl www.example.com/item/search?q=myquery&style=list, www.example.com/item/search?q=myquery&style=grid, or is there a better way to do this. below is a fiddle of my code and any refresh will return the view to grid even when i select list view
[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sammyzeal/tcfeymqu/)

Note: I'm using yii2 framework so regarding the url formation i'm open to both php and JS solution, thanks in advance

```
    $(".listView").on('click', function() {
  listView();
});

$(".gridView").on('click', function() {
  gridView();
});

// Get the elements with class="column"
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

// Declare a loop variable
var i;

// List View
function listView() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = "100%";
  }
}

// Grid View
function gridView() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = "50%";
  }
}


var container = document.getElementById("btnContainer");
var btns = container.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Comment: Simply store the preference in localStorage or sessionStorage, and then retrieve it from there; you don't need PHP at all for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you want, actually you dun need to do any work on backend but simply using the cookie.

You may improve it, I just provide a picture.

```
$(".listView").on('click', function() {
  listView();
  setCookie('list');
});

$(".gridView").on('click', function() {
  gridView();
  setCookie('grid');
});

function setCookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name;
}
```

And when you start the JS, check the cookie first by

```
var x = document.cookie;
if (x == 'list'){...}
else if (x == 'grid'){...}
```

You may also choose to use localStorage, the technical is the same. However, only when if you list and grid data has no difference, and no server data is further required.

Answer (score 0):

I think MatrixTai has the right idea, but I personally prefer usually localStorage.

Here is an example with a functions for getting/setting the view:

```
$(".listView").on('click', function() {
  listView();
  setView('list');
});

$(".gridView").on('click', function() {
   gridView();
   setView('grid');
});

function setView(view) {
  localStorage.setItem('view', view);
}

function getView(view) {
  return localStorage.getItem('view');
}
```